# How to display taxonomy value using xslt?

Tags: 2013, xslt, managed-metadata, item-styles

I have created an item template in ItemStyle.xsl to assign it to the CQWP.

My template is:

```
<xsl:template name="DepartmentsTemplate" match="Row[@Style='DepartmentsTemplate']" mode="itemstyle">

<xsl:variable name="DisplayTitle">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetTitle">
            <xsl:with-param name="Title" select="@Title"/>                                    
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>  

    <a onclick="sayHello('{@Title}')"> <xsl:value-of select="@Department" disable-output-escaping="yes"></xsl:value-of></a>
</xsl:template>
```

Here the value I am displaying in `@Department` is of type managed metadata field. It displays output like: `Department 2|c98ce851-88fd-41bc-a013-4a69dd6bae66` but I want to display Department 2 only.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the XSLT substring-before function:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@Department,'|')" disable-output-escaping="yes">
```

Comment: Thank you sir, can you help for my [this](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80641/unable-to-store-javascript-function-return-value-to-xslt-variable) query?

Answer (score 3):

Dave's solution fixes your problem with assumption your data always contains a `|`. If you want to make your solution a little more robust you could also write this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat(@Department, '|'), '|')" disable-output-escaping="yes"></xsl:value-of></a>
```

This will also work in the case that the string does not have a `|` in it.